# Django Double Escaping Quotes etc

Tags: python, django

I'm experiencing what I would consider somewhat strange behavior. Specifically if I have a string like this:

> **1984: Curriculum Unit**
>  
>         by Donald R. Hogue, Center for Learning, George Orwell
>  
>         
>  
>         "A center for learning publication"--Cover.

It results in the following after being auto-escaped by the Django template system:

> **1984: Curriculum Unit**
>  
>         by Donald R. Hogue, Center for Learning, George Orwell
>  
>         
>  
>         &quot;A center for learning publication&quot;--Cover.

The problem seems to be that the " (quote), which should become `&quot;` is being escaped twice, resulting in `&amp;&quot;`. This results in strange looking formatting. I'm using Django 1.0.2, so it should be up to date, (though I should note I'm using the Ubuntu 9.04 included package python-django) but this behavior seems contrary to the intended behavior.

I've looked a little at django.utils.html.py which includes the actual function:

> def escape(html):
>
> > """Returns the given HTML with ampersands, quotes and carets encoded."""
> >
> > `return mark_safe(force_unicode(html).replace('&','&amp;').replace('<','&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'",'&#39;'))`
>
> escape = allow_lazy(escape, unicode)

Anyway, that looks like it should escape the & before anything else, which would be fine. So my suspicion is that it is being called twice. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

**Update:** I was suspicious that it might have something to do with Ubuntu's Django, which it lists as "1.0.2-1" so I installed "1.0.2-final" and am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to think about escaping in 1.0 . If you have a template

```
<html>
 <body>
  & == &amp; in HTML
 </body>
</html>
```

It should encode the `&` to `&amp;` before printing.

If you have a variable

```
<html>
 <body>
  {{ msg }}
 </body>
</html>
```

and

```
def view(request) :
  msg = "& == &amp; in HTML"
```

if should be printed the same way.

The only time you want to do the encoding yourself is if you need to paste in raw html. Like:

```
def view(request) :
  msg = '<img src="http://example.com/pretty.jpg" />This picture is very pretty'
```

and in your template

```
<html>
 <body>
  {{ msg|safe }}
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is the behavior I would expect, but it isn't what I'm getting. For example, where you said above msg = "& == &amp; in HTML" I would get something like this: "&amp;&amp; == &amp;&amp;amp; in HTML" That is to say, it performs the escaping once, then escapes the & in the escaped result. Thanks for the prompt response though!

Comment: Well, I tried doing something like that, and it came out just fine. That being said though, my problem with my actual code is unrelated. I'm going to poke around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hardy har har,

Silly me, Google is so smart that they already escaped those chars in the XML I was parsing. Wouldn't you know it, an hour of fiddling only to realize Google outsmarted me again!

P.S. In case anyone else ever comes across a similar problem, I'm specifically referring to the XML returned when doing this sort of query: http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=1984 , the data is already escaped for you! That being said, it does put me on edge a little bit because putting |safe in my templates will mean that if I ever get data from another source that I don't trust so much... Anyway, thanks for reading!